# node js change image quality

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, image-quality

I am a beginner with node.js and I would ask you for advice. In MSSQL images are stored as varbinary [enter link description here](http://puu.sh/fvcld/5163919b72.png). I have written over the  application in nodejs that allows access to data. I need to select images from the database, converted from varbinary to image and change their quality and re-save them as varbinary. It is the building plans [enter link description here](http://puu.sh/fvcqB/84b1f8a09a.png), which have a size 1.5 - 3 MB, and I need it to  shrink.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize image in Node js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37115815/476716).

Answer (score 0):

sql.VarBinary data type will map to a buffer in node.js.

**JS Data Type To SQL Data Type Map**

- String -> sql.NVarChar
- Number -> sql.Int
- Boolean -> sql.Bit
- Date -> sql.DateTime
- Buffer -> sql.VarBinary
- sql.Table -> sql.TVP

When you retrieve your binary image data from the database, you can create a buffer.

```
var b64str = /* data fetched from the database */;
var buf = new Buffer(b64str, 'base64');
```

You should be able to send the image as a buffer back to the database, if you are using the [mssql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

```
request.input('input_parameter', sql.VarBinary, buf);
```