# node save image with lower quality

Tags: node.js, image-resizing

whith this code :

```
var img = req.body.img;
var data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
var nomeFile = Date.now()+"-"+req.session.documentoAperto+".png"

fs.writeFile('/root/appsistMe/public/AppMeFile/Utenti/'+req.session.nome+'/'+req.session.documentoAperto+'/'+nomeFile, buf);
```

i save a img send by the client.
the problem is that the image saved weighs a lot more than the original sent by the client.
there is a way to decrease the weighs of the image saved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize image in Node js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37115815/476716).

Comment: This is strange, because base64 usually produces much larger data than pre-encoded. Have you checked if image written to disk is still valid? Also check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6933413/6352710